Next.js upon URL rewrite in middleware.ts text chunk stream is got all at once in client
With proxy rewrite able to retrieve non-stream data as expected,
middleware.ts

const targetUrl = "https://www.externalapi.com/stream-text-data"
    if (pathname.startsWith("/proxy") {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(
        new URL(
          `${targetUrl}${pathname.replace("/proxy", "")}`,
          req.url
        ),
        {
          request: { headers: req.headers },
        }
      );

in the client,
chat.tsx

    "use client"
    const _response: any = await fetch(
      "/proxy/stream-text-data",
      _options
    ).catch((error) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(error);
    });
    while (loopRunner) {
      try {  
        const { value, done } = await reader?.read();
        if (done) { 
          loopRunner = false; 
          break;
        } else {
          const decodedChunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true }); 
          setStreaming(decodedChunk);
        }
      } catch (error) { 
         setError(error);
        break;
      }
    }

streaming works seamlessly (chunk by chunk text receptance from external api) only if direct uri (targetURI) is used in fetch, if proxy is used and if url rewrite happens at middleware.ts api is getting all stream of text chunks at once only at the end of response after a latency.
Please help understand what is missing and how to fix this . thanks!
